# Remove subView from View?

Tags: iphone, ios4, view, subview

I have 2 Views, each View have a ViewController.

I opened the first view early in TabController.

Then (when a line in a table is clicked) I use this to add my subview:

```
ENSListViewController *vc = [ENSListViewController alloc];
vc.folder_id = 1;
vc.folder_type = @"an";
[vc initWithNibName:@"ENSListViewController" bundle:nil];
[self.view addSubview:vc.view];
[vc release];
```

In the second view I try to remove this view again, but it ends in a EXC_BAD_ACESS:

```
- (IBAction)backToFolderList:(id)sender
{
[self.view removeFromSuperview];
}
```

Where is my mistake?

Comment: He can't do vc.view as he doesnt have a reference to it. Also he has released it.

Comment: I don't understand both f your answers... please help more easily

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are releasing vc by [vc release]; hence it is not getting object of superview..
you have to release it in -dealloc method